# Use serial port (COM) as LPT1

Tags: windows, serial-port, parallel-port

I have a device that needs to be plugged in to LPT1 to run a legacy software.

I am trying to find a workaround to get it running in a latptop (without parallel port, obviously). I have HL-340 USB-to-Serial cable plugged in and running, but Windows XP uses it as COM3.

Is there a way to use an arbitrary serial port as LPT1?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a copy-protection dongle. It's very unlikely that you'll be able to get that to work through a serial to parallel convert much less one of those *plus* a USB to serial converter.

Comment: It's very unlikely that anything using parallel port which is not a printer would work well on windows xp. As a last possible alternative, try getting a USB to parralel port cable.

Comment: Check if there is a port replicator or dock for your laptop.  Sometimes they have real serial and parallel ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'll be the `MODE` command (took me a while to recall that from my DOS days).

```
C:\> MODE LPT1=COM3
```

You can also use the `MODE` command to set up the baud rate of the serial connection:

```
C:\> MODE COM3:9600,N,8,1
```

[This page](http://www.easydos.com/mode.html) has all the usages of the `MODE` command.

Comment: Thanks,@MattJenkins, this would probably work for printers, but as @DennisWilliamson pointed out, my device can't work using this.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has a PCMCIA or PC Card Express slot, they make parallel adapters for these slots.